# How to close QWebSocket in thread?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt-signals

I move a QWebSocket to a thread, and then how can I close it in main thread?

Since I move it to worker thread, I cannot call close from main thread directly. It crash with this message

> QSocketNotifier: Socket notifiers cannot be enabled or disabled from another thread

Without threading, it works fine.

Here is my code. 
Any ideas? Thanks a lot!

```cpp
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QWebSocket>
#include <QThread>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
        Q_OBJECT

    public:
        explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
        ~MainWindow();

    private slots:
        void on_connectButton_clicked();
        void on_disconnectButton_clicked();

        void onClientConnected();
        void onClientClosed();
        void onClientTextMsg(const QString &msg);

    private:
        Ui::MainWindow *ui;
        QWebSocket *mClient;
        QThread mWorkerThread;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

```cpp
#include "MainWindow.h"
#include "ui_MainWindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow),
    mClient(nullptr)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    mWorkerThread.start();

    qRegisterMetaType<QAbstractSocket::SocketState>();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_connectButton_clicked()
{
    mClient = new QWebSocket();
    connect(mClient, &QWebSocket::connected, this, &MainWindow::onClientConnected, Qt::DirectConnection);
    connect(mClient, &QWebSocket::disconnected, this, &MainWindow::onClientClosed, Qt::DirectConnection);
    connect(mClient, &QWebSocket::textMessageReceived, this, &MainWindow::onClientTextMsg, Qt::DirectConnection);
    mClient->open(QUrl("ws://192.168.2.2:1936"));
    mClient->moveToThread(&mWorkerThread);
}

void MainWindow::on_disconnectButton_clicked()
{
    // FIXME crash
    // QSocketNotifier: Socket notifiers cannot be enabled or disabled from another thread
    mClient->close();
}

void MainWindow::onClientConnected() {
    qDebug() << "ws client connected";
}

void MainWindow::onClientClosed() {
    qDebug() << "ws client closed, " << mClient->closeReason() << mClient->errorString();
}

void MainWindow::onClientTextMsg(const QString &msg) {
    qDebug() << "ws recv msg:" << msg;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`QMetaObject::invokeMethod`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaobject.html#invokeMethod):

```
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(mClient, "close", Qt::QueuedConnection);
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. But I found a new problem. When in high latency network environment, it seems the client block the event loop in worker thread, maybe? The `close` method will not invoke util all msg received. How can I do to close the client immediately?

Comment: Finally, I found the anwser in QT source code `qwebsocketframe.pp`. Maybe I should change this code...
```
            //TODO: waitForReadyRead should really be changed
            //now, when a WebSocket is used in a GUI thread
            //the GUI will hang for at most 5 seconds
            //maybe, a QStateMachine should be used
            if (!pIoDevice->waitForReadyRead(5000)) { }
```